# "in sufficient numbers" OR "in/a sufficient number"?

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

The extract below is from an essay written by a private student of mine. The topic is about the measures a college could adopt to make it more environmentally friendly.

> Most of the colleges don't go further than the simple "paper" and "plastic" bins, which, in most of the cases, **are** not even **in sufficient number** to cover all the structures attended by students.

I am uncertain about the words in bold, should it be:

1. **are ... in sufficient numbers**
2. **are... a sufficient number**
3. None of the above. The original is acceptable
   *Most...**are... in sufficient number***

The term *number* is usually singular when it precedes a countable noun; e.g., *a/the **number** of bins*, *a/the **number** of colleges*, but what if it follows the subject? Should *number* become *numbers*?

I could rephrase that particular section:

> …**the number** of which, in most cases, **is insufficient** to cover…

But I would like to keep the word order and sentence structure as close as possible to the original.

Please help, I've been working quite a bit during the summer and my brain is totally *fritto* (fried), I just can't figure this one out.

Comment: You could substitute *present* for *even*.

Comment: @RichardKayser I'm sorry but I don't understand. Am I missing something? The word "present" is not used. Are you saying I could say *"...the number of which, at present, is insufficient..."*

Comment: Sorry if I was confusing. I was suggesting that you consider the following in the original text: *which, in most cases, are not present in sufficient number ..." You can keep all the original text with one word change.

Comment: @RichardKayser oh, please post it as an answer. Why does "present" work better instead of "even"?

Comment: *in ... numbers*, but you need another word. *... are not present/available/supplied in sufficient numbers*.

Comment: Incidentally, students don't *attend* structures, Just *cover all the classrooms/buildings* would be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripping away most of the unnecessary words, we have: "... **bins** **are** **not in sufficient number**", which seems awkward in that **bins** is plural and **not in sufficient number** *feels* singular. The following works better:

> ... **bins** **are** **not present in sufficient number**...

It has the added advantage of meeting your desire to keep the word order and sentence structure as close as possible to the original: all you have to do is substitute **present** for **even**.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting it. Sorry it's not more of a textbook answer.

Comment: I appreciate your "acceptance".